# subversion: How to: difference between modified working copy and alternate branch?

Tags: svn, diff, branch

I have tried.

My working copy is based on but a modified version of

```
svn://foo.net/svn/repo/branch/yyy
```

I want to diff against branch xxx. I have tried

```
svn diff --old=svn://foo.net/svn/repo/branch/xxx --new=.
```

but that only seems like shorthand for

```
svn diff --old=svn://foo.net/svn/repo/branch/xxx --new=svn://foo.net/svn/repo/branch/yyy
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems that subversion doesn't allow to compare working copy with url. Both --old and --new need to be either WC or URL.

I think there's a workaround though - you may checkout your `xxx` branch and then compare 2 working copies.

```
svn checkout svn://foo.net/svn/repo/branch/xxx xxx_branch
```

<del>svn diff xxx_branch yyy_modified_wc</del>

```
diff -u xxx_branch yyy_modified_wc
```

**Edit** As Pavel noticed `svn diff` in this form doesn't compare xxx and yyy - it just shows local modifications of xxx and yyy. `svn diff --old=xxx --new=yyy` seems not allowed (at least in svn client 1.6.17). To compare xxx and yyy `diff` command is needed. Pavel, 10x for the notice

Comment: The question was about comparing against *modified* working copy. However `svn diff` shows some difference where simple `diff` does not - thus your method does not take modifications into account (that was requested I believe).

Answer (score 0):

You can also compare between two urls : it's faster because you don't have to checkout the other branch.

```
svn info # grap url
svn diff localUrl distantUrl
```

Comment: No. It shows differences between two branches. To make it "work", you'll have to commit on the branch you're working on, otherwise the url "trick" won't work.

Did I misunderstood the question?